# What is the solution for systems of linear inequalities in three variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, numerical-methods, gaussian-elimination

|  | Meal 1 | Meal 2 | Meal 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Milk (%) | 10 | A | B |
| Meat (%) | 10 | 12 | A |
| Veggies (%) | C | 4 | 12 |

These are milk, meat and veggies rates of meals. A, B and C values will be given as the input.
In order to make the daily requirement of milk, meat and veggies at least 100%, in order to keep the total amount of meals(Meal 1, Meal 2 and Meal 3) taken to a minimum, how many units these meals should be added to the unit diet program.

For example: These are given: A = 15, B = 20 and C = 20;

I created this matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}10&15&20\\10&12&15\\20&4&12\end{bmatrix}

When I solve with this equation with Gauss elimination method, I found these values: 
M1 = 6.74   M2 = 10.87  M3 = -6.52 
However, quantity of Meal 3 cannot be equal to a negative number.
I mean, these should be $$ M1 \geq 0 , M2 \geq 0 \ and \ M3 \geq 0 $$

Daily requirement is eg. total percentage of milk should be **at least 100%**. Also, total percentage of meat should be **at least 100%** and total percentage of veggies should be **at least 100%**.
It means that $$10x + 15y + 20z  \geq 100 $$ $$10x + 12y + 15z  \geq 100 $$ $$20x + 4y + 12z  \geq 100 $$

How can I find the solution set of the smallest numbers of meals that satisfy these constraints?

Comment: I don't see where the daily requirements are given.

Comment: @saulspatz Daily requirement is eg. total percentage of milk should be at least 100%. Also, total percentage of meat should be at least 100% and total percentage of veggies should be at least 100%.

Comment: This sounds like a linear programming problem to me.  Have you studied that?

Comment: I created a program with python for Gauss elimination however I do not know how I can handle inequalities of this linear system.

Comment: Gaussian elimination won't work.  Linear programming is a mathematical subject.  It has nothing to do with computer programming.  Here the problem is minimize $x+y+z$ subject to the inequalities you have stated, together with $x,y,z\geq0$

Comment: Yes, what is the way should I follow to solve the inequalities?

Comment: You can try use simplex method.  If you are studying linear programming, this should have been covered in your course.  If not, search the Web for "linear programming", and you'll find bunches of elementary expositions.

Comment: @saulspatz My course is about numerical analysis. I will search simplex method, thank you.

Comment: Good luck.  I just feel I ought to point out the problem with Gaussian elimination.  When you try to subtract two of your inequalities, the sense of the second one changes, so you can't say anything meaningful.

Comment: Are only integer numbers of meals allowed? If so, then this is really a problem of integer programming rather than linear programming (though the two are related).

Comment: Also, the fact that $x,y,z$ can't be negative means that $$10x+15y+20z\geq 10x+12y+15z\geq 100.$$ This has a simple meaning in the context of the problem: Each meal is at least as nutritious in milk as it is in meat, so any combination of meals which fulfills the meat requirement will also fulfill the milk requirement. Hence the first condition can be dropped. (This is dependent on your choice of A,B,C and would not be true in general.)